# How does Ubuntu One upload music metadata changes?

Tags: ubuntu-one, music, metadata

I've been recently editing quite a lot of mp3 files, basically editing mp3 tags. I've got all my music collection stored in Ubuntu One, so any time I edit any songs, the changes get uploaded to the cloud.

I was wondering, does U1 upload the whole music file when editing its metadata (e.g. ID3 tags), or is there a way in which it detects that this metadata has been changed and just a portion of the file is uploaded?

Comment: I think it just replaces the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu One does not currently support diff-style uploads, and whenever a file changes, the whole file is re-uploaded.